# How to reset my password if I forgot it?

Tags: users

I forgot the admin user pass for my site. Then I followed the process to recover my password. I get an email with a link (available for 24hs) which allows me to login in my site. I go to 'user/1/edit' to create a new password, but the old one is a REQUIRED field. This is wrong, I forgot my password, then I can't fill this field.

Am I missing something here??

Comment: do you access database tables?

Comment: It's simple with drush: ```drush upwd --password="mynewpassword" my_user```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can change admin password either by [drush](https://www.drupal.org/node/44164) or by running [mysql query](https://www.drupal.org/node/1023428) if you have access to database if you do not have direct access to your mysql server, install devel and wrap the mysql query with drupal query wrapper functions and run it at /devel/php page.

You may want to consider having [nocurrent_password](https://www.drupal.org/project/nocurrent_pass) module which removes the current password field and you can directly update your passwords, NOTE: this behaviour will be same for other users as well.

Comment: It worked: https://www.drupal.org/project/nocurrent_pass thanks

Comment: If you have drush, you can use `drush uli` which generates a one time login link

Comment: login link still can be generated from Forgot Password page issue lies in the fact that drupal still asks for old password before resetting a new ome

Answer (score 0):

If you can see user/1/edit then you must be logged in, right? Log out and use the link in the email and it will ask you to reset your password. Then there should only be two fields in a non-logged in page for you to fill in.

Comment: No, I'm logout, it is the link in the email which allows me to login.

Comment: (Safely) disable any modules that add functionality to your login process--vanilla Drupal doesn't ask for a current password.